# Crouch speed is faster than Movement Speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In short, when I click the CTRL key, my player goes down but it goes faster than when it moves normally, why?

```
public float movementSpeed = 10.0f;
public float crouchSpeed = 2.0f;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
{
    isCrouching = true;
}

if (isCrouching == true)
{
    controller.height = crouchingHeight;
    float curSpeedX = canMove ? (isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : movementSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") : 0;
    float curSpeedY = canMove ? (isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : movementSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") : 0;
    movement *= crouchingMulitplier;
    float movementY = movement.y;
    movement = (transform.forward * curSpeedX) + (transform.right * curSpeedY);
}
```

Comment: Not enough code. You dont show your movement code. Or the multiplier value

Comment: You already reduce the speed of crouching from `movementSpeed` to `crouchSpeed` ... so what exactly is the `crouchingMulitplier` good for at all? And what is its value?

Comment: Sorry I misread. Yeah, you need to show us more of the code. What happens when he's not crouching?